# Android imageview src changing

Tags: android, imageview

I want to make ImageView which changing image. ImageView is running man and I want to make his ranning?

- How can I change ImageView src with code but with best perfomance...
- Can I use GiF animation on layout?

Comment: you want animate a series of images?

Comment: frame animation is the way, as it is mentioned on below answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame Animations - that's the easiest if you only have few images.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Answer (score 0):

costantly? 1000 time at second?
gif doesn't work on layout... you can usa an animation, or a thread (slow)

[Animate multiple imageviews dependently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534806/animate-multiple-imageviews-dependently)

quick animation guide 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-animations-quick-guide.html

Comment: NO 1000 time at second i want to make runing man,and i want to use less resources..

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti

### Or

Use GIF in project using `implementation pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.4`.

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/mygif"/>
```